# I am trying to assemble my thesis but I am having troubles

Tags: report

I have started assembling my thesis, and ran up into problems while assembling it. My chapters and appendices are in folder called "Chapters". Here is my main file:

```
\documentclass[12, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\graphicspath{{./Chapters/Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Methodology}
\input{Chapters/Methodology.tex}

\appendix
\chapter{Tables}
\input{Chapters/table.tex}

\end{document}
```

Here is Introduction.tex

```
\begin{document}
My introduction text
\end{document}
```

Here is Methodology.tex:

```
\begin{document}
My methodology text
\end{document}
```

Here is table.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{table-format =1.2e-2}
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Potentially Important Amplified Genes}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

1 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \\ 
  2 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\ 
  3 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\ 
  4 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \\ 
  5 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  7 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  8 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  9 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \\ 
  10 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  11 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  12 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  13 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  14 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\ 
  15 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\ 
  16 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \\ 
  17 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  18 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  19 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  20 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  21 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  22 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  23 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  24 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  25 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  26 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  27 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \\ 
  28 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\ 
  29 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\ 
  30 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\ 
  31 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\ 
  32 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \\ 
  33 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \\ 
  34 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\ 
  35 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\ 
  36 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  37 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  38 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  39 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  40 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  41 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  42 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  43 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  44 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  45 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  46 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  47 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  48 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  49 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  50 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  51 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  52 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  53 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \\ 
  54 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \\ 
  55 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \\ 
  56 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \\ 
  57 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  58 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  59 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  60 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  61 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  62 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  63 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  64 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  65 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  66 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  67 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  68 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  69 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  70 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\ 
  71 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\ 
  72 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \\ 
  73 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \\ 
  74 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 \\ 
  75 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  76 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\ 
  77 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\ 
  78 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  79 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  80 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  81 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I have two problems. First, tables.tex works fine when compiled on its own, but not when I insert it in the main file. Second, if I only include Introduction.tex and Methodology.tex, only Introduction.tex appears. I didn't include my full texts because of space. I would greatly appreciate any input. Thank you!

Comment: By creating a MWE ( http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that ), you can narow down your problem, and most likely find the error yourself.

Comment: your files should be just like this : `My introduction text` `My methodology text` and `\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}` no preambl no document environment just body code

Comment: Of course, you will need to add any required packages and customisations to your main file's preamble e.g. `xcolor`, `\sisetup` etc.

Answer (score 2):

When using `\input`, your file should not have any `\usepackage` or `\begin{document}\end{document}`

Note that every package have be added to the preamble in the main.

main:

```
\documentclass[12, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\graphicspath{{./Chapters/Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Methodology}
\input{Chapters/Methodology.tex}

\appendix
\chapter{Tables}
\input{Chapters/table.tex}

\end{document}
```

Introduction:

```
My introduction text
```

Methodology:

```
My methodology text
```

tables:

```
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{table-format =1.2e-2}
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Potentially Important Amplified Genes}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

1 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \\ 
  2 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\ 
  3 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\ 
  4 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \\ 
  5 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  7 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  8 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\ 
  9 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \\ 
  10 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  11 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  12 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  13 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\ 
  14 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\ 
  15 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\ 
  16 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \\ 
  17 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  18 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  19 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  20 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\ 
  21 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  22 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  23 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  24 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  25 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  26 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\ 
  27 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \\ 
  28 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\ 
  29 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\ 
  30 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\ 
  31 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\ 
  32 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \\ 
  33 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \\ 
  34 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\ 
  35 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\ 
  36 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  37 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  38 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  39 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  40 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  41 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  42 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  43 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  44 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  45 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  46 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  47 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  48 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  49 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  50 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  51 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  52 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\ 
  53 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \\ 
  54 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \\ 
  55 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \\ 
  56 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \\ 
  57 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  58 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  59 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  60 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  61 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  62 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\ 
  63 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  64 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  65 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  66 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  67 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  68 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  69 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\ 
  70 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\ 
  71 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\ 
  72 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \\ 
  73 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \\ 
  74 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 \\ 
  75 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\ 
  76 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\ 
  77 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\ 
  78 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  79 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  80 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\ 
  81 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```